# when from a tab to another the table is distorted

Tags: javascript, html, css

a web page with tabs, after refreshing the page the table for each tab is displayed correctly, but when I switch from one tab to another the table is distorted

my code:

```
<section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-section-1" id="sec-2ee8">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <div class="u-tab-links-align-left u-tabs u-tabs-1">
          <ul class="u-spacing-10 u-tab-list u-unstyled" role="tablist">
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-1" role="presentation">
              <a class="active u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-1 bouton" id="link-tab-14b7" href="#tab-14b7" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-14b7" aria-selected="true"> Afficher les données de la technicentre CASABLANCA</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-2" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-2 bouton2" id="link-tab-0da5" href="#tab-0da5" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-0da5" aria-selected="false"> Afficher les données de la technicentre Marrackech</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-3 bouton3" id="link-tab-2917" href="#tab-2917" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-2917" aria-selected="false"> Afficher les données de la technicentre</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-4" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-4 bouton4" id="tab-6e5a" href="#link-tab-6e5a" role="tab" aria-controls="link-tab-6e5a" aria-selected="false"> Editer des données</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-5" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-5 bouton5" id="link-tab-1729" href="#tab-1729" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-1729" aria-selected="false"> Supprimer des données</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-6" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-6 bouton8" id="link-tab-f632" href="#tab-f632" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-f632" aria-selected="false"> Ajouter des éléments au stock</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-7" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-7 bouton9" id="link-tab-1bbe" href="#tab-1bbe" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-1bbe" aria-selected="false"> Sortir des éléments du stock</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-8" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-8 bouton6" id="link-tab-aebf" href="#tab-aebf" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-aebf" aria-selected="false"> Afficher les entrées</a>
            </li>
            <li class="u-tab-item u-tab-item-9" role="presentation">
              <a class="u-active-grey-10 u-button-style u-tab-link u-text-active-black u-text-black u-tab-link-9 bouton7" id="link-tab-f61c" href="#tab-f61c" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-f61c" aria-selected="false"> Afficher les sorties</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="u-tab-content">
            <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-active u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-1" id="tab-14b7" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-14b7">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-valign-top u-container-layout-1">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">Données du Technicentre Casablanca</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-1"></div>

                <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                <div id="resultat"></div>
                
                <script>
                  // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                  function afficherFichierCasablanca() {
                    // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    
                    // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                    xhr.open("POST", "afficher_casablanca.php", true);
                    
                    // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                        document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                      }
                    };
                    
                    // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                    xhr.send();
                  }

                  // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                  document.querySelector('.bouton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                    document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                    afficherFichierCasablanca();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                  });
                </script>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-2" id="tab-0da5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-0da5">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-valign-top u-container-layout-2">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Données du Technicentre Marrackech</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>
                  <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                  <div id="resultat2"></div>
                                  
                  <script>
                    // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                    function afficherFichierMarrackech() {
                      // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      
                      // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                      xhr.open("POST", "afficher_Marrakech.php", true);
                      
                      // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                          // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                          document.getElementById("resultat2").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      
                      // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                      xhr.send();
                    }

                    // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                    document.querySelector('.bouton2').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                      document.getElementById("resultat2").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      afficherFichierMarrackech();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                    });
                  </script>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-3" id="tab-2917" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-2917">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-3">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Données du Technicentre</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>
            
                <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                <div id="resultat3"></div>
            
                <script>
                  // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                  function afficherFichier() {
                    // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
                    // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                    xhr.open("POST", "afficher_tout.php", true);
            
                    // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat3"
                        document.getElementById("resultat3").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                      }
                    };
            
                    // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                    xhr.send();
                  }
            
                      // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque la page est chargée
                      window.addEventListener('load', afficherFichier);
                      document.querySelector('.bouton3').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      document.getElementById("resultat3").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      afficherFichier();
                });

                </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            

            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-4" id="link-tab-6e5a" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-6e5a">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-4">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Edition des données</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>

                  <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                  <div id="resultat4"></div>
                                                    
                  <script>
                    // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                    function editerFichier() {
                      // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      
                      // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                      xhr.open("POST", "page_edition.php", true);
                      
                      // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                          // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                          document.getElementById("resultat4").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      
                      // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                      xhr.send();
                    }

                    // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                    document.querySelector('.bouton4').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                      document.getElementById("resultat4").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      editerFichier();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                    });
                  </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-5" id="tab-1729" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-1729">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-5">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Suppression des données</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>

                  <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                  <div id="resultat5"></div>
                                                    
                  <script>
                    // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                    function supprimerFichier() {
                      // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      
                      // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                      xhr.open("POST", "page_supprimer.php", true);
                      
                      // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                          // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                          document.getElementById("resultat5").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      
                      // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                      xhr.send();
                    }

                    // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                    document.querySelector('.bouton5').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                      document.getElementById("resultat5").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      supprimerFichier();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                    });
                  </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-6" id="tab-f632" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-f632">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-6">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Ajout des données</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>              
                <div id="resultat8"></div>
                                                    
                <script>
                  // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                  function ajouterFichier() {
                    // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    
                    // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                    xhr.open("POST", "page_ajouter.php", true);
                    
                    // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                        document.getElementById("resultat8").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                      }
                    };
                    
                    // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                    xhr.send();
                  }

                  // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                  document.querySelector('.bouton8').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                    document.getElementById("resultat8").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                    ajouterFichier();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                  });
                </script>
          
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-7" id="tab-1bbe" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-1bbe">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-7">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Sortie des données</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>              

                
                  <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                  <div id="resultat9"></div>
                                                    
                  <script>
                    // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                    function sortirFichier() {
                      // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      
                      // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                      xhr.open("POST", "page_sortir.php", true);
                      
                      // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                          // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                          document.getElementById("resultat9").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      
                      // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                      xhr.send();
                    }

                    // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                    document.querySelector('.bouton9').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                      document.getElementById("resultat9").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      sortirFichier();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                    });
                  </script>
        
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-8" id="tab-aebf" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-aebf">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-8">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Affichage des entrées</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>

                  <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                  <div id="resultat6"></div>
                                                    
                  <script>
                    // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                    function afficherentree() {
                      // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      
                      // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                      xhr.open("POST", "input_afficher.php", true);
                      
                      // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                          // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                          document.getElementById("resultat6").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      
                      // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                      xhr.send();
                    }

                    // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                    document.querySelector('.bouton6').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                      document.getElementById("resultat6").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      afficherentree();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                    });
                  </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="u-container-style u-grey-10 u-tab-pane u-tab-pane-9" id="tab-f61c" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="link-tab-f61c">
              <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-9">
                <h5 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-4">Affichage des sorties</h5>
                <div class="u-border-3 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-expanded-width u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-3"></div>

                  <!-- Ajoutez un élément où le contenu sera affiché -->
                  <div id="resultat7"></div>
                                                    
                  <script>
                    // Fonction pour effectuer la requête AJAX
                    function affichersortie() {
                      // Créez un objet XMLHttpRequest
                      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      
                      // Définissez la méthode et l'URL de la requête
                      xhr.open("POST", "sortie_afficher.php", true);
                      
                      // Définissez la fonction de rappel pour gérer la réponse
                      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                          // Mettez la réponse dans l'élément avec l'ID "resultat"
                          document.getElementById("resultat7").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                      };
                      
                      // Envoyez la requête (vous pouvez également envoyer des données POST si nécessaire)
                      xhr.send();
                    }

                    // Appelez la fonction afficherFichier lorsque le bouton est cliqué
                    document.querySelector('.bouton7').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); // Empêchez le formulaire de se soumettre normalement
                      document.getElementById("resultat7").innerHTML = ""; // Réinitialisez le conteneur
                      affichersortie();  // Appelez la fonction pour afficher le fichier
                    });
                  </script>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

execution :

Directly after refreshing the page:

[image]

after switching between tabs:

[image]

a solution to this probleme

Comment: When you refresh you get 2 extra columns in the table???? Why is that? It could explain

Comment: no it'not when i refresh , when i refresh it's display correctly , but when i switch between tabs, it's display like in this pictures

Comment: All I see is the same URL on 2 pages/tabs but the data presented is different. I dont see a specific distortion only different data. What distortion are you talking about?

Comment: Particularly when i switch from the "Afficher les sorties" tab, which contains six columns.

Comment: It's the same data, but in the first picture, it's presented with 8 columns, while in the second picture, it's shown with 6 columns.

Comment: If possible consider refactoring this with an actual table or a css grid would work nicely. Why? They consistently work properly and you save time by not having to debug this current problem.